# How to Initialize a C# Selenium webdriver test to pass in different browser types?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to pass into my unit tests which browser to use (Firefox, Chrome, IE).

```
    [TestInitialize()]
    public void Initialize(string URL, string Country, string Browser)
    {
        this.URL = URL;
        this.Country = Country;
        this.Browser = Browser;
    }
```

Something like:

```
    public DefaultDriver _webDriver  = new DefaultDriver();
```

Then assign the Default Driver to the correct Browser type:

```
        if (Browser == "Firefox")
            _webDriver = _firefoxDriver;
        else if (Browser == "Chrome")
            _webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        else if (Browser == "IE")
            _webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

But this doesnt work as there is no DefaultDriver that is compatible with ChromeDriver, FireFoxDriver, and InternetExplorerDriver that I can find.  What would be a good way to do this or another way to accomplish sending in the browser type in C#?  I'm using a form application to run the tests and want to pass in different browsers to the same test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
WebDriver _webDriver = null;
if (Browser == "Firefox")
    _webDriver = _firefoxDriver;
else if (URL == "Chrome")
    _webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
else if (URL == "IE")
    _webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Comment: +1.  @George, you probably mean each line to check the Browser, not the URL, and I would recommend changing it to a switch statement.

Comment: using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

private RemoteWebDriver _webDriver;

Worked.

Answer (score 3):

The WebDriver project makes extensive use of interfaces. While all current browser-specific implementations descend from `RemoteWebDriver`, that's not a requirement. What you really want is to use the `IWebDriver` interface.

```
public IWebDriver _webdriver = null;
```

Then in your factory method do something like:

```
switch (browser)
{
    case "IE":
        _webdriver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    case "Firefox":
        _webdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;
    case "Chrome":
        _webdriver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
}
```